# Get all checked and unchecked true or false value in array jQuery ajax and submit it to Laravel controller

Tags: php, html, laravel

How to give default value to checkbox false and when I checked it give me output true with his name like:`("user_management_create":true)` at the time of form submit if I can't check any checkbox it, also gives false value `like(User_management_erite:false)`

I want output like this `{"dashboard":true,"user_management_read":true,"user_management_write":false", content_management_read":false,"content_management_write":true}`

## HTML

```html
<form id="kt_modal_add_role_form1"> <tr>
        <!--begin::Label-->
        <td class="text-gray-800">Content Management</td>
        <!--end::Label-->
        <!--begin::Options-->
        <td>
            <!--begin::Wrapper-->
            <div class="d-flex">
                <!--begin::Checkbox-->
                <label
                        class="form-check form-check-sm form-check-custom form-check-solid me-5 me-lg-20">
                    <input class="form-check-input checkitem"
                           type="checkbox" value=""
                           name="content_management_read"
                           class="checkitem" />
                    <span class="form-check-label">Read</span>
                </label>
                <!--end::Checkbox-->
                <!--begin::Checkbox-->
                <label
                        class="form-check form-check-sm form-check-custom form-check-solid me-5 me-lg-20">
                    <input class="form-check-input checkitem"
                           type="checkbox" value=""
                           name="content_management_write"
                           class="checkitem" />
                    <span class="form-check-label">Write</span>
                </label>
                <!--end::Checkbox-->
                <!--begin::Checkbox-->
                <label
                        class="form-check form-check-sm form-check-custom form-check-solid">
                    <input class="form-check-input checkitem"
                           type="checkbox" value=""
                           name="content_management_create"
                           class="checkitem" />
                    <span class="form-check-label">Create</span>
                </label>
                <!--end::Checkbox-->
            </div>
            <!--end::Wrapper-->
        </td>
        <!--end::Options-->
    </tr>
```

Comment: This is not how checkboxes work. you will have to do some issets on `$_POST` if the checkbox is checked it will be set with a value of on. you can change the default on value by setting a true value however it will be an empty value when its not checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked class="custom-control-input" id="switch2" name="status">
```

In Controller File Write code like these :

```
$subject->status = $request->status == 'on'?'1':'0';
```